# How to turn off scientific notation for double when appending it to ostringstream?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, scientific-notation, ostringstream

I have a small function which converts double to std::string:

```
std::string convertDoubleToString( double value ) {
    std::ostringstream ostr;
    ostr << value;
    return ostr.str();
}
```

I don't want to use the scientific notation here. How can I do it in this case? I can use std::fixed or cout.setprecision but it works for std::cout only but how can I use it for my case?

Comment: What makes you think it only works for `cout`?  Have you tried it?

Comment: A stream is a stream is a stream... And all streams basically works the same with regards to [manipulators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip).

Comment: By the way, you probably want to take a look at [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [std::fixed](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed) manipulator like this:

```
 ostr << std::fixed << value;
```

Comment: Didn't know it works for all streams as well. Worked this way: *ostr << std::fixed << std::setprecision( 10 ) << value;* - without setprecision it returns too "short" value :)